# Find avg difference in dates stored as strings

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation, mongotemplate

I have a Mongo database and I have stored dates as strings. Per document I have a field called "creationdate" and a field called "completiondate". The dates format is "YYYY-MM-dd" (ex "2011-12-18"). Even I can execute simple aggregation like greaterThan, greaterThanEqual, I cannot find the difference in dates, which I have to find to calculate the average days difference between completion and creation date.

The above query I have to write it on spring-boot with MongoTemplate if it is possible.

I am trying something like this but it doesn't work.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("creationdate").gte(date1).lte(date2).andOperator(Criteria.where("completiondate").ne(""))),
                Aggregation.project("servicerequesttype").and(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("completiondate").withFormat("%Y-%m-%d")).minus(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("creationdate").withFormat("%Y-%m-%d")).as("diff"),
                Aggregation.group("servicerequesttype").avg("diff").as("average")
        );
```

date1, date2 are given strings like "2011-01-01"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      creationdate: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$creationdate",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      },
      completiondate: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$completiondate",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      difference: {
        $subtract: [
          "$completiondate",
          "$creationdate"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      average: {
        $avg: "$difference"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      dayAverage: {
        $divide: [
          "$average",
          86400000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I have created interactive demo here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wGRw12m3UbB

Hope it helps :)

Comment: yes it finds the average date but I cannot execute the equivalent in spring-boot. I have to group by a field named "servicerequesttype" and I have match criteria (creationdate greater than a given string-date).

Answer (score 0):

Spring-Boot

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("creationdate").gte(date1).lte(date2).andOperator(Criteria.where("completiondate").ne(""))),
                Aggregation.project("servicerequesttype").and(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("creationdate").withFormat("%Y-%m-%d")).as("creationdate").and(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("completiondate").withFormat("%Y-%m-%d")).as("completiondate"),
                Aggregation.project("servicerequesttype").and("completiondate").minus("creationdate").as("difference"),
                Aggregation.group("servicerequesttype").first("servicerequesttype").as("servicerequesttype").avg("difference").as("temp"),
                Aggregation.project("servicerequesttype").and("temp").divide(86400000).as("average")
        );
```